# Configure different environment variables for older versions using Flux CD Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, flux

I have a very well-configured deployment using Flux CD Helm chart.
This deployment is making sure that always 3 replicas of the last 3 versions are deployed.
I want now to add an environment variable (that my project code uses) that will have different values for each of the 3 versions.
How can I do it?

I tried to read the files and did not understand the correct way to do it